# Nokia Qt SDK and Qt Mobility API

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, nokia

It looks like Nokia Qt SDK does not provide QtMultimediaKit with the package which is a part of [Qt Mobility API](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/new-qt-apis/) 1.0.2.

e.g. I cannot use QMediaPlayer to play *.mp4 file (Simbiot^3)

```
 QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;

 playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
 playlist->append(QUrl("http://example.com/myfile1.mp4"));
 playlist->setCurrentPosition(1);
 player->play();
```

Is anyone know how to configure the Nokia Qt SDK with QMediaPlayer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of day googleing, I found answer from Nokia Forum. They're not appear to be google able :-(

> Qt Mobility will be part of Qt 4.7 and for Qt 4.6 it's a separate library/package.

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?199772-Is-QT-mobility-part-of-Nokia-QT-SDK

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the qmediaplayer example, it is included in the SDK install, but it uses the platform's codecs (by default Phonon+DShow backend on Windows, Phonon+installed backends on Linux, Phonon+Quicktime on Mac). If you have qmediaplayer, but can't play an mp4-file, you will need to install codecs to support playing that file.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the QMediaPlayer class which able to use in Simbiot^3